# ASP.NET Raw SQL Escape Comma with Decimal Type

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, escaping

Question is in the title, how can I escape commas of a given decimal? Do I really need to workaround: get the value, convert it to String, replace commas with dots?

Is there a simpler solution to this? Or is there a good library or function I can use for this?

**EDIT**: I know I can enter values by replacing commas with dots. I'm asking for internal functions or external libraries for escaping SQL queries, as StringEscapeUtils in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having re-read your post it looks to me like the best way to be sure is to change the culture to en-US before you run your SQL statement. This will change all commas to dots in numbers. So something like

> Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
>               CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the current culture. You're culture is using dot as a separator.

Consider this code where you provide a culture that uses comma as a separator:

```
var dec = "123,45";

decimal parsed;
decimal.TryParse(dec, NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("es-ES"), out parsed);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm trying to ask a way to Escape Decimal Commas (ex. 123,3) and run an SQL Query without comma problems.

Comment: So you're concatenating strings to queries? If so, it seems as an injection-prone solution.

Comment: Yes, it is. But the project will be working on a localhost, for locals only, and injection is not a problem for me. And beware: there are some angry men around, which don't like people who answers "it's injection-prone" to SQL Query questions.